# Modelagem de dados para produtos

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

[image]

Fiz um diagrama no Workbench de acordo com as instruções acima, é sobre o controle de vendas em uma mercearia.

[image: Diagrama com modelo]

Meu professor de banco de dados falou algo sobre não conseguir estar visualizando a diferenciação de preço dos produtos de mesmo tipo mas marcas diferentes. Por exemplo: Um macarrão instantâneo de 2 marcas diferentes, nessa tabela, teriam o mesmo preço(de acordo com ele). Como posso resolver isso? Uma tabela somente para o preço e uma relação N-M entre ela e a tabela produto?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Modelagem é algo que depende de requisitos concretos. Com requisitos artificiais qualquer coisa pode ser certa ou errada. Dentro da minha experiência real fazendo sistemas, seu modelo está certo porque se a marca é diferente o produto é diferente e deve ter outro cadastro. Não faz o menor sentido tentar controlar objetos com especificações diferentes (por mínima que seja, e essa nem é mínima, é praticamente máxima) como se fosse uma coisa só.

Para fazer diferente precisaria de uma clareza e precisão de requisitos mostrando exatamente o que precisa ser feito, afinal o que está sendo pedido não é intuitivo e não é o que você terá que fazer em um cenário real. Por isso eu preferiria justificar isso em vez de refazer o modelo. Pode ser que só faltou você justificar melhor como seria feito o cadastramento e porque este modelo é adequado, aí seu professor tem razão, porque apesar de certo se você entendeu porque ele está certo, é o mesmo que você não saber, e ele quer que você saiba, não só apresente o resultado. Por outro lado, seu professor também pode estar querendo impor a visão dele e aí só faria sentido se ele tivesse dado requisitos muito claros. Ele pode ter dado e você não ter colocado na pergunta para podermos ajudar mais.

Se não quiser confrontá-lo faça o que parece que ele dá a entender só para agradá-lo, mesmo sabendo que provavelmente é um erro. Aí eu nem saberia exatamente o que fazer, muita coisa poderia ser diferente, mas como todas parecem erradas, seria um chute oferecer qualquer uma delas.

Eu acho que teria um relacionamento 1:N com `marcas` e tudo menos o `id`, `nome` (nossa, isso parece tão errado) e `categoria` passaria para esta tabela. Pra falar a verdade se tirar o nome, eu tiraria, porque o da marca Nissin tem um nome e o da marca Renata tem outro nome, aí essa tabela de produto no fundo passa ser uma tabela de categoria e a tabela de marcas passa de novo ser uma tabela de produtos. Algo como:

```
produto
-------
id
nome
categoria

marca
-----
id
produto_id
preço
quantidade
fornecedor_id
```

Inclusive em cenário real existe uma diferença entre fabricante e fornecedor.

De qualquer forma se for fazer algo certo eu vejo vários erros nesse modelo, alguns porque ele é um exercício e não é completo. Por isso precisa ser analisado de forma diferente. Curiosamente ele parece aceitar esses vários erros do que seria m cenário real, mas quer introduzir um erro conceitual.

Retiro tudo o que eu disse se a pergunta não estiver clara o suficiente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta. Provavelmente o professor irá corrigir em sala amanhã, se caso eu lembrar trago uma explicação mais completa do que ele deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa estratégia é criar uma tabela preço, nela pode conter marca, mas como isso é um atributo de produto, o correto deveria ser, cada produto, ter uma marca, e o mesmo ter uma referência na tabela preço, com o id do produto como chave estrangeira o preço, e algum eventual atributo.

Um exemplo de um banco de dados um pouco mais complexo que fiz:

[image: Outro bd]

Comment: Vou tentar isso, obrigado! :)

Answer (score -1):

Cara, estou trabalhando em um banco de dados mais complexo, basicamente estou com uma dúvida de modelagem, mais pelo fato de aplicar a um padrão utilizado no mercado atual e tenho muito tempo de desenvolvimento e nesse tempo minha modelagem é meio que pessoal em questão ao diagrama. Estudando muito acabei parando aqui, e lendo tua "incerteza" acabei parando para analisar tua modelagem, aliás muito bem feita pois é complicado para novos desenvolvedores entender o uso da chave estrangeira.

Vamos ao primeiro ponto, não sei se ainda tem a mesma dúvida pois se passaram 1 ano, o segundo, com total certeza posso afirmar que o seu professor quis te causar uma dúvida em sua modelagem pois está muito bem feita para um aluno fechando faculdade. O ponto de chaves estrangeiras "foreign key" é a relação segura entre tabelas, isso significa que ao analisar, sei que seria impossível não relacionar categorias com preços, ou até mesmo fornecedores, pois avaliando a regra de uma FK (chave estrangeira), o id relacionado deve ser único em sua tabela proprietária, e esse id você usaria para relacionar itens, não sei se entendeu mas vou explicar melhor abaixo.

Você tem a tabela produtos que relaciona o id UNICO da tabela categoria, o produto tem seu preço, porém a categoria dele pode ser diferente, você poderia ter 5 produtos diferentes com o mesmo preço, mas, 2 destes produtos não tem a mesma categoria, sendo assim, ao procurar produtos com o mesmo preço você encontraria os 5 produtos, mas, simplesmente procurando produtos com o mesmo preço e com a mesma categoria, você teria apenas 3 ou 2 produtos em sua consulta, dependendo da categoria que você especifica-se em sua consulta. Acho desnecessário aumentar o número de tabelas apenas para uma relação de preços, pois isso seria muito complexo no ponto de vista da pessoa que vai consultar esse banco, ela teria que consultar outra tabela, e ao mudar o preço de 1 produto, se este estiver relacionado, você poderia acabar mudando o preço de 3 produtos, sendo que um dos produtos não devesse ter seu preço alterado.

De duas perguntas, uma é a mais forte, seu professor viu essa modelagem e provavelmente por te conhecer não pensou que pudesse ter essa sabedoria para produzir tal, ou a outra, se ele imaginar que você pudesse fazer tal feito, ele talvez iria querer saber como chegou a esse ponto de relacionamento de tabelas, pois o que maioria faria para fazer esse tipo de relação, seria como citado pelo ultimo amiguinho a cima, fazer uma tabela para armazenar apenas os preços o que é um completo erro no ponto de vista de pessoas que fossem utilizar o seu programa, pois 1 produto pode ter o mesmo preço que outro, porém, 1 produto pode ter seu preço alterado e o outro pode manter o mesmo preço, apesar do amiguinho não estar errado, isso iria gerar uma dor de cabeça imensa a quem estivesse trabalhando com este banco de dados.

Conclusão, pense comigo, se você tiver uma tabela apenas para preços, e tiver que alterar o preço de apenas 1 produto, sendo que 20 produtos tem o mesmo preço na tabela, você teria que adicionar mais uma linha em sua tabela de preços para apenas 1 produto, sendo que é mais fácil armazenar o preço de cada produto na tabela produtos.

Parabéns pela modelagem, se foi você quem fez, estudou bastante e está no caminho certo, o amiguinho que respondeu primeiro o *Maniero soube explicar de forma mais simples ao entendimento geral, uma resposta muito boa, com certeza um programador mais experiente. Grande abraço!